# How to wait for a Promise to resolve without using callbacks

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a function that returns a promise. How can I wait for the promise to resolve snd then restart the code execution without using the `.then()` callback? Or basically:

```js
const returnValue = promiseFunc()
console.log(returnValue) // I want the promise to resolve before this executing
```

I know that this works:

```js
promiseFunc().then(returnValue => {
    console.log(returnValue)
})
```

but I have code which looks a bit like this:

```js
for (/*conditions*/) {
    // code
    promiseFunct()
    // code
}
```

I have no idea how to put that into a callback.

Comment: Use `await promiseFunc()`

Comment: `const returnValue = await promiseFunc()`